# my page keep refreshing when i press the submit button

Tags: javascript, html

i use `input type:"button"` because if i use `type="submit"` my page refresh

here is the button

`<input type="button" value="Submit" align="center" Onclick="hitung()" class="myButton">`

this is `hitung()` function

```js
function hitung(){

var e = (document.getElementById("ifin").value);
var panjang = parseFloat (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
var hf = 0.0;
var lebar = 0.6;
var tinggi = 0.8;
var total = 0.0;

if (e == "hpl") {

    hf = 1.7;
   }
else if(e == "cat")
   {
    hf = 2.0;
}
else {
    hf = 0.0;
}
total = lebar*tinggi*panjang*hf;
document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML =eval(total);
}
```

i need to use `type:submit` because if i use like that, i cant use `required` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that your `hitung()` function returns `false`. At the end of the function, simply add the following line:

```
return false;
```

If you don't want to change the function, you can achieve the same by changing the call:

```
<input type="submit" value="Submit" align="center" Onclick="hitung(); return false;" class="myButton">
```

Comment: You are welcome. Please feel free to mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the default behavior of a submit button you can use jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function($) {
  $(document).on('submit', '#formsubmit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    alert('page did not reload');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id='formsubmit'>
  <button type='submit'>submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code

```js
function hitung(event){

var e = (document.getElementById("ifin").value);
var panjang = parseFloat (document.getElementById("ipanjang").value);
var hf = 0.0;
var lebar = 0.6;
var tinggi = 0.8;
var total = 0.0;

if (e == "hpl") {

    hf = 1.7;
   }
else if(e == "cat")
   {
    hf = 2.0;
}
else {
    hf = 0.0;
}
total = lebar*tinggi*panjang*hf;
document.getElementById("ototal").innerHTML =eval(total);
event.preventDefault();
event.stopPropogation();
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Submit" align="center" Onclick="hitung(event)" class="myButton">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use submit, you need to prevent default.

Read this so you can learn how it works and how to implement, instead just copying and pasting. Then if you have questions, just ask.
Here is the documentation.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 0):

If you want to proceed with submit only if the form is valid, then use [reportValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) and return the output of same from your method.

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" align="center" onsubmit="return hitung(this)" class="myButton">

function hitung( thisFormElement )
{
   //rest of the logic

   return thisFormElement.reportValidity();
}
```